# By kotlin.. trouble with reading data from database by firebase to RecyclerView

Tags: android, database, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have trouble with reading data from database by firebase.
the code supposed read data from database to RecyclerView..but no working..

the app is work without bugs or error and if writ some data inside recyclerView will go to database without any trouble, but no data show in recyclerView..

............

MainActivity code >>>

```
class MainVote : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.main_vote)

    RecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
    val votes = ArrayList<VotePublic>()


    // Here start reading data code from database in firebase

    val db= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    db.child("votedata").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot?) {

            val values = p0!!.value as HashMap<String,Any>

            for (k in values.keys){

                val data = values[k] as HashMap<String,Any>

                votes.add(
                    VotePublic(

                    data["quesVote"] as String ,
                            data["vote11"] as String ,
                            data["vote22"] as String ,
                            data["vote33"] as String ,
                            data["vote44"] as String

                    ))
            }

           val myadaper = CastumAdapter(votes,this)
           RecyclerView.adapter = myadaper

        }

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) {

        }
    })
```

CustomAdapter Class.. >>

```
class CastumAdapter(val votelist: ArrayList<VotePublic>, val context: ValueEventListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CastumAdapter.MyViewHolder> () {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): MyViewHolder {

    val view = LayoutInflater.from(p0.context).inflate(R.layout.raw_re2,p0,false)
    return MyViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {

    return votelist.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, p1: Int) {

    val votepublic : VotePublic = votelist[p1]

    holder.setData(votepublic, p1)

}

inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

// some code here..
 .
 .
 .
 .

 fun setData(datavote: VotePublic?, pos: Int) {

        this.currentHobby = datavote
        this.currentPosition = pos

       }
   }
}
```

And this is a JSON sample for database structure:

```
{
"project_info": {
"project_number": "836053259827",
"firebase_url": "https://vote-app-****",
"project_id": "vote-app-****",
"storage_bucket": "vote-app-****.appspot.com"
},
"client": [
{
  "client_info": {
    "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:836053259827:android:****",
    "android_client_info": {
      "package_name": "com.example.dell.vote1"
    }
  },
  "oauth_client": [
    {
      "client_id": "****-hlqj7at8n5tvhmllgr82p7k9ssvl3f8l.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "client_type": 1,
      "android_info": {
        "package_name": "com.example.dell.vote1",
        "certificate_hash": "****"
      }
    },
    {
      "client_id": "****-glt9h6b98k7bc2m1390rbogn7tioo70a.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "client_type": 3
    }
  ],
  "api_key": [
    {
      "current_key": "****_-9t6BVPeE4g8eQ"
    }
  ],
  "services": {
    "analytics_service": {
      "status": 1
    },
    "appinvite_service": {
      "status": 2,
      "other_platform_oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "****-glt9h6b98k7bc2m1390rbogn7tioo70a.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    "ads_service": {
      "status": 2
      }
    }
  }
],
"configuration_version": "1"
}
```

Comment: The database structure meaning a JSON sample or at least a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

probably missing:

```
myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```